# Last occurrence index in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to long string fields. e.g. `val1|val2|....|val300`

I have max char limit and I want to keep whole value field. e.g. I don't want to have - `val1|val2|....|va`

To keep under max char limit, I am using `substr(1, k)`. Now I need last occurrence of `|` .

I can find first occurrence using:

```
df = df.withColumn("COL_1", F.locate('|', F.col('COL'), 1))
```

How to find the last occurrence of `|` in Pyspark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way using [substring_index](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.substring_index):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import substring_index, length

df.withColumn('COL_1', length('COL') - length(substring_index('COL', "|", -1))).show()                      
+--------------------+-----+
|                 COL|COL_1|
+--------------------+-----+
|val1|val2|....|va...|   15|
+--------------------+-----+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `reverse` the string before you use `locate` and then substract the index from the `length` of the string:

```
df.withColumn("COL_1", length(col("url")) - locate('|', reverse(col("url")))).show()
```